# Internet explorer 8 compatiblity

Tags: internet-explorer-8

How to make my web application running in web logic 12 c server to render in IE 8 mode always irrespective of IE (VERSION  9,10,11) Without adding any meta tags

Comment: Why no meta tags?

Comment: Too many(3500) htmls are there ..and our product team doesnot allow us to checkin

Answer (score -1):

If you can send the X-UA-Compatible as an HTTP header, that will work too.

```
X-UA-Compatible: IE=8
```